# Why is clearfix not working on this column?

Tags: css, multiple-columns, clearfix, row-height

I've recently taken over a few hubspot pages ffrom someone before me who built them.  On this particular page, I have two columns— one on the left, and one on the right (has a gray background).  The left column currently has more content than the right, so the gray background of the right column does not extend all the way down the page, but instead stops at the bottom of its own content.  No big deal right?  I'll just use clearfix..  But clearfix is doing nothing.  Ok, I'll just use JavaScript... but after trying to different scripts, it's not working either.  I've tried multiple version of the clearfix hack.

Can someone help me get this dang gray background from the right column to extend all the way down to the bottom of the page (the same height as the left column)?  I would be in your debt!

Here's the page: http://info.brushresearch.com/end-brushes

Here's the most recent CSS code I was using:

```
.z-clearfix:after {
         visibility: hidden;
         display: block;
         font-size: 0;
         content: " ";
         clear: both;
         height: 0;
         }
    .z-clearfix { display: inline-block; }
    /* start commented backslash hack \*/
    * html .z-clearfix { height: 1%; }
    .z-clearfix { display: block; }
    /* close commented backslash hack */
```

Here's the basic HTML I'm using...

```
<div class="z-clearfix">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-cell page-center content-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 0px;" data-widget-type="cell" data-x="0" data-w="12">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-2 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span6 widget-span widget-type-cell main-content" style="padding: 20px 0;" data-widget-type="cell" data-x="0" data-w="6">

<div class="row-fluid-wrapper row-depth-1 row-number-3 ">
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span12 widget-span widget-type-widget_container " style="" data-widget-type="widget_container" data-x="0" data-w="12">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1395325065960295" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_2876866323" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_rich_text" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="rich_text"><h2>Power Brushes for Small, Tight, And Hard-to-Reach Spaces</h2>
<h3>End Brushes</h3>
<p><br><img src="//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/484035/hubfs/Landing_Pages/End_Brushes.jpg?t=1458145818376&amp;width=230" alt="End Brushes" title="End Brushes" width="230" data-constrained="true" style="width: 230px; float: left; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;">End brushes&nbsp;are used for cleaning, blending, polishing, deburring, and surface finishing&nbsp;recessed areas.</p>
<p>Industrial and automotive applications include cleaning parts, polishing dies, and removing carbon deposits from piston heads, cylinders, and valve seats.</p>
<h4>Types of End Brushes</h4>
<p><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container">Brush Research Manufacturing (BRM)&nbsp;supplies these&nbsp;types of&nbsp;end brushes:</span></p>
<ul>
<li><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><strong>Solid Wire</strong> for blending, cleaning, and polishing</span></span></li>
<li><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><strong>Knotted</strong>&nbsp;<strong>Wire</strong> for added aggressiveness</span></span></span></li>
<li><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><span class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><strong>Circular Flared</strong>&nbsp;for side cutting action</span></span></span></span></li>
</ul>
<p>Most end brushes have&nbsp;carbon steel or stainless steel filaments.&nbsp;Nylon, abrasive nylon, and brass filaments are available for some solid end brushes.</p>
<p>End brushes also differ in terms of end-style. Brushes with standard ends are great for general-purpose use.&nbsp;Banded tools have less trim and produce less flare. End brushes with coated cups protect the workpiece from contact with the metal body. &nbsp;</p>
<h4>Which End Brush Do You Need?</h4>
<p>Which end&nbsp;brush is right for your&nbsp;application?&nbsp;<span>Watch the video and download the BRM&nbsp;Product Catalog to&nbsp;learn more.</span></p>
<div><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gm624K5y79k" width="425" height="350"></iframe></div></div></span>
</div><!--end widget-span -->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end row-wrapper -->

</div><!--end widget-span -->
<div class="span6 widget-span widget-type-widget_container sidebar right" style="background: #ececec;padding: 20px 80px;/*padding-bottom:30em;*/" data-widget-type="widget_container" data-x="6" data-w="6">
<span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_14019004881245786" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container"><div id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_13885068285937553" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_form" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="form"><h3 id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_13885068285937553_title" class="hs_cos_wrapper form-title" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_field" data-hs-cos-type="text">Download The BRM Product Catalog</h3>

<div id="hs_form_target_module_13885068285937553"><form novalidate="" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/484035/67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hsForm_67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" method="POST" class="hs-form stacked hs-custom-form" data-form-id="67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887" data-reactid=".0"><fieldset class="form-columns-2" data-reactid=".0.1:$0"><div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your First Name" for="firstname-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.0.0">First Name</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.$firstname"><input id="firstname-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="firstname" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$firstname.$firstname.0"></div></div><div class="hs_lastname field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" for="lastname-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.0.0">Last Name</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.$lastname"><input id="lastname-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="lastname" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$0.1:$lastname.$lastname.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$1"><div class="hs_company field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Company Name" for="company-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.0.0">Company Name</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.$company"><input id="company-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="company" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$1.1:$company.$company.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-2" data-reactid=".0.1:$2"><div class="hs_phone field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" for="phone-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.0.0">Phone Number</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.$phone"><input id="phone-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="tel" name="phone" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$phone.$phone.0"></div></div><div class="hs_email field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Email" for="email-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.0.0">Email</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.$email"><input id="email-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="" value="" data-reactid=".0.1:$2.1:$email.$email.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$3"><div class="hs_address field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Street Address" for="address-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.0.0">Street Address</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.$address"><input id="address-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="address" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$3.1:$address.$address.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$4"><div class="hs_city field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your City" for="city-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.0.0">City</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.$city"><input id="city-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="city" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$4.1:$city.$city.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-2" data-reactid=".0.1:$5"><div class="hs_state field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your State/Region" for="state-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.0.0">State/Region</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.$state"><input id="state-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="state" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$state.$state.0"></div></div><div class="hs_zip field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Postal Code" for="zip-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.0.0">Postal Code</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.$zip"><input id="zip-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="zip" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$5.1:$zip.$zip.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$6"><div class="hs_country field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Country" for="country-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.0.0">Country</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.$country"><input id="country-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" type="text" name="country" required="" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$6.1:$country.$country.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$7"><div class="hs_hs_persona field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Customer Type" for="hs_persona-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.0.0">Customer Type</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona"><select id="hs_persona-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" required="" class="hs-input" name="hs_persona" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.0">- select -</option><option value="persona_1" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_1">Industrial Manufacturer</option><option value="persona_2" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_2">Industrial Distributor</option><option value="persona_3" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_3">Automotive End-User</option><option value="persona_4" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_4">Firearms End-User</option><option value="persona_5" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_5">Automotive Distributor</option><option value="persona_6" data-reactid=".0.1:$7.1:$hs_persona.$hs_persona.0.1:$persona_6">Other</option></select></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$8"><div class="hs_industry_dropdown field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Application" for="industry_dropdown-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.0.0">Application</span><span class="hs-form-required" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.0.1">*</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown"><select id="industry_dropdown-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" required="" class="hs-input" name="industry_dropdown" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.0">- select -</option><option value="Aerospace" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Aerospace">Aerospace</option><option value="Automotive" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Automotive">Automotive</option><option value="Earth Moving Equipment" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Earth Moving Equipment">Earth Moving Equipment</option><option value="Firearms" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Firearms">Firearms</option><option value="Forming and Fabricating" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Forming and Fabricating">Forming and Fabricating</option><option value="Fluid Power" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Fluid Power">Fluid Power</option><option value="General Industrial Manufacturing" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$General Industrial Manufacturing">General Industrial Manufacturing</option><option value="Hydraulics" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Hydraulics">Hydraulics</option><option value="Marine" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Marine">Marine</option><option value="Metalworking" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Metalworking">Metalworking</option><option value="MRO" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$MRO">MRO</option><option value="Musical Instruments" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Musical Instruments">Musical Instruments</option><option value="Oil and Gas" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Oil and Gas">Oil and Gas</option><option value="Welding" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Welding">Welding</option><option value="Military" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Military">Military</option><option value="Other" data-reactid=".0.1:$8.1:$industry_dropdown.$industry_dropdown.0.1:$Other">Other</option></select></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$9"><div class="hs_comments field hs-form-field" data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Comments" for="comments-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments.0.0">Comments</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments.$comments"><textarea id="comments-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" class="hs-input" name="comments" placeholder="" data-reactid=".0.1:$9.1:$comments.$comments.0"></textarea></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$10"><div class="hs_lifecyclestage field hs-form-field" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Lifecycle Stage" for="lifecyclestage-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage.0.0">Lifecycle Stage</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage.$lifecyclestage"><input name="lifecyclestage" class="hs-input" type="hidden" value="marketingqualifiedlead" data-reactid=".0.1:$10.1:$lifecyclestage.$lifecyclestage.0"></div></div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-columns-1" data-reactid=".0.1:$11"><div class="hs_campaign field hs-form-field" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign"><label class="" placeholder="Enter your Campaign" for="campaign-67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887_8120" data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign.0"><span data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign.0.0">Campaign</span></label><legend class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign.1"></legend><div class="input" data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign.$campaign"><input name="campaign" class="hs-input" type="hidden" value="Website" data-reactid=".0.1:$11.1:$campaign.$campaign.0"></div></div></fieldset><div class="hs_submit" data-reactid=".0.3"><div class="hs-field-desc" style="display:none;" data-reactid=".0.3.0"></div><div class="actions" data-reactid=".0.3.1"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="hs-button primary large" data-reactid=".0.3.1.0"></div></div><input name="hs_context" type="hidden" value="{&quot;pageUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.brushresearch.com/end-brushes&quot;,&quot;pageTitle&quot;:&quot;End Brushes| Power Brushes | BRM&quot;,&quot;isHostedOnHubspot&quot;:true,&quot;timestamp&quot;:1458148249926,&quot;userAgent&quot;:&quot;Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36&quot;,&quot;referrer&quot;:&quot;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018345/why-is-clearfix-not-working-on-this-column&quot;,&quot;hutk&quot;:&quot;d54500098a6cf0a8c80e3558e469aada&quot;,&quot;originalEmbedContext&quot;:{&quot;portalId&quot;:&quot;484035&quot;,&quot;formId&quot;:&quot;67fcbcac-a5a7-44f8-93c3-81bfcc503887&quot;,&quot;formInstanceId&quot;:&quot;8120&quot;,&quot;pageId&quot;:3854020261,&quot;pageName&quot;:&quot;End Brushes| Power Brushes | BRM&quot;,&quot;redirectUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.brushresearch.com/brm-product-catalog-thank-you&quot;,&quot;css&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;#hs_form_target_module_13885068285937553&quot;,&quot;contentType&quot;:&quot;landing-page&quot;,&quot;formData&quot;:{&quot;cssClass&quot;:&quot;hs-form stacked hs-custom-form&quot;}},&quot;formName&quot;:&quot;Request Literature Catalog, Flex-Hone, &amp; Nampower&quot;,&quot;recentFieldsCookie&quot;:{},&quot;pageId&quot;:&quot;3854020261&quot;,&quot;pageName&quot;:&quot;End Brushes| Power Brushes | BRM&quot;,&quot;boolCheckBoxFields&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;dateFields&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;redirectUrl&quot;:&quot;http://info.brushresearch.com/brm-product-catalog-thank-you&quot;,&quot;formInstanceId&quot;:&quot;8120&quot;,&quot;smartFields&quot;:{},&quot;urlParams&quot;:{},&quot;formValidity&quot;:{}}" data-reactid=".0.4"></form></div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the backend of the hubspot template page:

[Screenshot of the Hubspot Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyM0A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can add class in parent element :

```
<div class="row-fluid " style="position: relative;">
```

And you can do that for your sidebar right :

```
element.style {
    background: #ececec;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    /* padding-bottom: 30em; */
}
```

I try and its works.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.  So just to clarify, I'm adding the .row-fluid class to what element specifically?

And then I'm applying the supplied CSS code to .sidebar.right?